# Membership Type Use Case

Tags: civimember

What is the best way to configure a membership for the following scenario on a WordPress platform?

The base membership for an organization will be $425/yr. This allows them to add a max of 4 members. For each member they wish to add over 4 it's an additional fee of $125 per person.

Comment: This is actually quite a complex requirement - we have done similar for clients but as they were using Drupal we could use Webforms and find a work around - mentioning the CMS you are using is helpful

Comment: Hi @petednz-fuzion! Thanks for responding. I'm using WordPress for my CMS.